# Наследование Java автосалон

Tags: java

Подскажите, где здесь можно применить наследование:

```
public class Car {

public String name;
public String bodyType;
public int price;

public String toString() {
    return name + "(" + bodyType + ")" + " - " + price + "$";
}

}




class HeavyCarInitializator extends Car  {

public static String[] names = {
        "DAF XF 105", "Volvo FH16", "Renault Magnum", "Mercedes Actros", "Scania S500", "ЗИЛ 157", "МАЗ 2021"};
private static final int[] price = {30000, 100000, 65000, 80000, 90000, 15000, 19000};
public static final String[] bodyType = {"Mixer","Truck","Garbage","Crane","Garbage","Crane","Truck"};

public static void init(Car[] HeavyCars) {
    for (int i = 0; i < HeavyCars.length; i++) {
        HeavyCars[i].name = names[i];
        HeavyCars[i].price = price[i];
        HeavyCars[i].bodyType = bodyType[i];

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать класс `BodyType`, который будет отвечать за "Mixer","Truck" и т.д., и класс `Car`, который будет наследоваться от `BodyType`.

Comment: *минус не мой. Вопрос вполне себе по теме, просто ОЧЕНЬ плохо сформулирован.